# Ingest data in timescaleDB from kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, telegraf, timescaledb

I want to ingest data from a topic into timescaleDB.
I have seen as options: jdbc connector or telegraf but i dont know if its proper or how to do it.

Somebody has any idea of how to do it?

thank you.

Comment: Your question is extremely broad. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". Where have you searched, what did you try, and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently published a blog post on how to do just this: https://blog.timescale.com/blog/create-a-data-pipeline-with-timescaledb-and-kafka/

In short, we recommend using Kafka's PostgreSQL sink: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc